# Add a separator in GWT flextable row

Tags: gwt

I have a flex table in GWT , it has 3 rows . Now I want to draw a line / separator after every row .(just separator between rows, Not for column)

can i acheive this ..

here's the current screen

You can see 3 rows , just need a clean and nice  line between them [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `FlexTable` is rendered as just a `<table>` with their cells being simple `<td>`s. So in your CSS you can include something like this:

```
.tableWithRowsDelimiter td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
}
```

And then assign the `tableWithRowsDelimiter` style to your `FlexTable`, via ui.xml:

```
<g:FlexTable ui:field="yourFlexTable" class="tableWithRowsDelimiter"/>
```

Or in your Java code:

```
yourFlexTable.setStyleName("tableWithRowsDelimiter");
```